# json_decode not working in php

Tags: php, json

Please check my below code and please let me know ehat wrong I am doing , I just want to decode the json and print on the browser as array

```
<?php

$json = '{
"Token" : "xxx-xxx-xxx",
"ID": "1",
"Recipients": [
    {
        "Recipient_ID": "XX",
        "From_Name": "XXX",
        "From_Email": "XXX",
        "To_Name": "XXX",
        "To_Email": "XXX",
        "Subject": "XXX",
        "Message": "XXX",
        "Attachments": [
            {
                "File_Name": "XXX",
                "File_Path": "XXX",
            }
        ],
    }
],
}';

$input = $json;
print_r(json_decode(stripslashes($input)));

?>
```

I tried this json string to decode online (http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/) and its working fine so no issue with json string. Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: You have 3 trailing `,` that you shouldn't have.

Comment: your json is also not valid look my updated answer

Comment: remove , at end of json string

Comment: @Jon Stirling : Its 2 trailing ,

Comment: @RakeshSojitra It's 3.

Comment: @Jon Stirling : Ohh yes its 3

Comment: Thanks guys for all your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$json = '{
    "Token": "xxx-xxx-xxx",
    "ID": "1",
    "Recipients": [{
        "Recipient_ID": "XX",
        "From_Name": "XXX",
        "From_Email": "XXX",
        "To_Name": "XXX",
        "To_Email": "XXX",
        "Subject": "XXX",
        "Message": "XXX",
        "Attachments": [{
            "File_Name": "XXX",
            "File_Path": "XXX"
        }]
    }]
}';

$input = $json;
var_dump(json_decode(stripslashes($input)));

?>
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what you changed from current one ?

Comment: you can copy the json I mentioned in the answer, I removed three extra commas

Answer (score 0):

the problem stand from the json format you have.. You have some ',' that needs to be removed and that's why the json_decode() can't do his job. This function throws an error exception but you should do a little trick to view the error. 
You can use this code to view the error.

```
switch (json_last_error()) {
    case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
        echo ' - No errors';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
        echo ' - Maximum stack depth exceeded';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
        echo ' - Underflow or the modes mismatch';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
        echo ' - Unexpected control character found';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
        echo ' - Syntax error, malformed JSON';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
        echo ' - Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded';
    break;
    default:
        echo ' - Unknown error';
    break;
}
```

And you json should be like this.

```
$json = '{
"Token" : "xxx-xxx-xxx",
"ID": "1",
"Recipients": [
    {
        "Recipient_ID": "XX",
        "From_Name": "XXX",
        "From_Email": "XXX",
        "To_Name": "XXX",
        "To_Email": "XXX",
        "Subject": "XXX",
        "Message": "XXX",
        "Attachments": [
            {
                "File_Name": "XXX",
                "File_Path": "XXX"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}';
```

Comment: Thanks for better explainations :)